# How to find files/folders recursively in Perl script?

Tags: perl, module, find

I have a perl script which I have written to search files present in my windows folders, recursively. I enter the search text as the perl script runtime argument to find a file having this text in it's name. The perl script is as below:

```
use Cwd;

$file1 = @ARGV[0];    

#@res1 = glob "*test*";
#@res1 = glob "$file1*";
@res1 = map { Cwd::abs_path($_) } glob "$file1*";
foreach (@res1)
{
    print "$_\n";
}
```

But this is not searching all the sub-directories recursively. I know `glob` doesn't match recursively.
So tried using module `File::Find` and the function  `find(\&wanted,  @directories);`

But I got a error saying `find()` undefined. From what I read from help, I thought `find()` function is defined by default in Perl installation, with some basic code to find folders/files. Isn't it correct?

Questions is, in the above perl script, how do I search for files/folders recursively?

Second questions, I found that `perldoc <module> help` does not have examples about using a certain function in that module, which would make it clear.

Can you point to some good help/document/book for using various perl functions from different perl modules with clear examples of usage of those module functions.

Comment: My method from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979310/extended-for-subdirectories-rename-files-and-directories-add-prefix could help. The task in this case was to rename all the files and folders in a directory and all subdirectories. The method could easily be modified for your uses.

Answer (score 18):

Another excellent module to use is [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.32/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm) which hides some of the complexity of [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.12.3/lib/File/Find.pm) while exposing the same rich functionality.

```
use File::Find::Rule;
use Cwd;

my $cwd = getcwd();
my $filelist;

sub buildFileIndex {
    open ($filelist, ">", "filelist.txt") || die $!;

    # File find rule
    my $excludeDirs = File::Find::Rule->directory
                              ->name('demo', 'test', 'sample', '3rdParty') # Provide specific list of directories to *not* scan
                              ->prune          # don't go into it
                              ->discard;       # don't report it

    my $includeFiles = File::Find::Rule->file
                             ->name('*.txt', '*.csv'); # search by file extensions

    my @files = File::Find::Rule->or( $excludeDirs, $includeFiles )
                                ->in($cwd);

    print $filelist map { "$_\n" } @files;
    return \$filelist;
}
```

Comment: I think there may be two little errors with this code, (for any 'noob' trying it) First, there is no link to the subroutine itself, so nothing would be actioned. (need "&buildFileIndex;" under getcwd(); )Also, the "open" txt file isn't "closed", so the file would not be readable by other code. Just a thought

Answer (score 5):

These two pages are all you need to study:

- [File::Find documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html)
- [Beginners guide to File::Find](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=217166)

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on stackexchange sites. A short code example, like in other answers, would have been very welcomed.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative would be to use find2perl to create the start of the script for you.  It can turn a find command like,

```
find . -type f -name "*test*" -print
```

To an equivalent perl script.  You just put find2perl instead of find.  It uses File::Find under the hood but gets you going quickly.

Comment: Thanks. Learn't this find2perl and found it very useful starter to get some default file search scripts which I cna play with.

Comment: Indeed, I think Alessandro's answer is really better but to get you going find2perl is really useful.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind using cpan module, [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Path%3a%3aClass) can do the work for you:

```
use Path::Class;

my @files;
dir('.')->recurse(callback => sub {
    my $file = shift;
    if($file =~ /some text/) {
        push @files, $file->absolute->stringify;
    }
});

for my $file (@files) {
    # ...
}
```

Comment: BTW, good news, in my testing, this appears to also work on a fresh copy of OSX Lion (10.8.5) all the way up to my last test I did on OSX El Capitan (10.11) without having to install the module. So, if you were like me, building an installer that relied on this working by default -- it does.

Answer (score 1):

```perl
use 5.010; # Enable 'say' feature
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find; # The module for 'find'

find(\&wanted, @ARGV); # @ARGV is the array of directories to find.

sub wanted {
  # Do something...

  # Some useful variables:
  say $_; # File name in each directory
  say $File::Find::dir; # the current directory name
  say $File::Find::name; # the complete pathname to the file
}
```

Example for listing driver modules on Linux (Fedora):

```
use 5.022;
use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX qw(uname);
use File::Find;

my $kernel_ver = (uname())[2];
my @dir = (
  "/lib/modules/$kernel_ver/kernel/drivers"
);

find(\&wanted, @dir);

sub wanted {
  say if /.*\.ko\.xz/;
}
```