# Search file in directory structure

Tags: perl, search

Does anybody know a method to search for a file in a directory structure without using `File::Find`? I know step-by-step how to do it but if it is possible to make it smoother that will be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find files/folders recursively in Perl script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089680/how-to-find-files-folders-recursively-in-perl-script)

Comment: What's wrong with `File::Find`?!

Comment: There are a variety of ways, but the default built in is probably the best, for all sorts of reasons. Either that, or `File::Find::Rule`. There are a lot of gotchas with directory traversal, that you don't have to worry about if you use a module.

Comment: the thing is that I cannot install any module. SECURITY

Comment: @PopescuEmanuel `File::Find` is a core module. No need to install anything.

Comment: @Biffen, It's hard to use right, but like the OP said, it's not smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From one `File::Find` hater to another: `DirWalk.pm`, inspired by the Python's `os.walk()`.

```
package DirWalk;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my ($class, @dirs) = @_;

    my @odirs = @dirs;

    @dirs = qw/./ unless @dirs;
    s!/+$!! for @dirs;
    s!/+\.$!! for @dirs;

    my $self = { _odirs => [@odirs], _dirs => [@dirs], _dhstack => [], _dnstack => [] };

    opendir my($dirh), $dirs[0];
    return undef unless $dirh;
    shift @{ $self->{_dirs} };
    unshift @{ $self->{_dhstack} }, $dirh;
    unshift @{ $self->{_dnstack} }, $dirs[0];

    return bless $self, $class;
}

sub _walk_op {
    my ($self) = @_;
    if (wantarray) {
        my @ret;
        while (defined(my $x = $self->next())) {
            push @ret, $x;
        }
        return @ret;
    }
    elsif (defined wantarray) {
        return $self->next();
    }
    return undef;
}

sub next
{
    my ($self) = @_;
    my $dstack = $self->{_dhstack};
    my $nstack = $self->{_dnstack};
    if (@$dstack) {
        my $x;
        do {
            $x = readdir $dstack->[0];
        } while (defined($x) && ($x eq '.' || $x eq '..'));

        if (defined $x) {
            my $nm = $nstack->[0].'/'.$x;
            if (-d $nm) {
                # open dir, and put the handle on the stack
                opendir my($dh), $nm;
                if (defined $dh) {
                    unshift @{ $self->{_dhstack} }, $dh;
                    unshift @{ $self->{_dnstack} }, $nm;
                }
                else {
                    warn "can't walk into $nm!"
                }
                $nm .= '/';
            }
            # return the name
            return $nm;
        }
        else {
            closedir $dstack->[0];
            shift @$dstack;
            shift @$nstack;
            unless (@$dstack) {
                while (@{ $self->{_dirs} }) {
                    my $dir = shift @{ $self->{_dirs} };
                    opendir my($dirh), $dir;
                    next unless defined $dirh;
                    unshift @{ $self->{_dhstack} }, $dirh;
                    unshift @{ $self->{_dnstack} }, $dir;
                    last;
                }
            }
            return $self->next();
        }
    }
    else {
        return undef;
    }
}

use overload '<>' => \&_walk_op;
use overload '""' => sub { 'DirWalk('.join(', ', @{$_[0]->{_odirs}}).')'; };

1;
```

Example:

```
# prepare test structure
mkdir aaa
touch aaa/bbb
mkdir aaa/ccc
touch aaa/ccc/ddd

# example invocation:
perl -mDirWalk -E '$dw=DirWalk->new("aaa"); say while <$dw>;'

#output
aaa/ccc/
aaa/ccc/ddd
aaa/bbb
```

Another example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DirWalk;

# iteration:
my $dw = DirWalk->new("aaa");
while (<$dw>) {
    print "$_\n";
}

# or as a list:
$dw = DirWalk->new("aaa");
my @list = <$dw>;
for (@list) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Comment: What advantages does this have over previously mentioned File::Find::Rule?

Comment: @PopescuEmanuel: So you can't use core modules from the Perl installation, or tried and tested ones from CPAN, but it's fine to copy and use an unknown and untested module from a random place on the internet? This is strange security

Comment: @ikegami, if you ask me. `File::Find::Rule` is a big messy thing which is not installed by default. While my `WalkDir` is a small thing which I can adapt if need to. Plus, the `WalkDir` actually walks tree as you iterate over it: it doesn't gobble everything into the list like `File::Find::Rule`. But personally, I have nothing against the `File::Find::Rule` except that when I needed it, it wasn't there.

Comment: To summarize: You said that FFR uses more memory than WalkDir.

Comment: @ikegami, I wrote the `WalkDir` after I have seen the Python's `os.walk()` - how simple and elegant it is compared to the incorrigible cruft of Perl's `File::Find`. No big thoughts/etc were involved - definitely no lengthy analysis and comparison of available CPAN modules - I just wanted something simple to iterate over subdirs/files.

Answer (score 2):

File::Find is a core module since perl 5.000 so I don't see a reason for not using it.

But if you still want to take your crazy way you could call the `find` command.

Answer (score 0):

The method I've been inplamenting is utilizing three commands: opendir, readdir, and closedir.  See below for an example:

```
opendir my $dir1, $cwd or die "cannot read the directory $cwd: $!";
@cwd= readdir $dir1;
closedir $dir1;
shift @cwd; shift @cwd;
foreach(@cwd){if ($_=~/$file_search_name/){print "I have found the file in $_\n!";}}
```

The directory will be stored in @cwd, which includes . and .. For windows, shift @cwd will remove these.  I unfortunately am tight for time, but utilize this idea *with an anon array to store the directory handles as well as another array for storing the directory paths*.  Perhaps utilize -d to check if it is a directory.  There might be file permission issues, so perhaps unless(opendir ...) would be a great option.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure I will be flayed alive for this answer but you could always use either system() or backticks `` to execute the regular linux find command.  Or do some sort of ls...

```
@files = `ls $var/folder/*.logfile`
@files = `find . -name $file2find`
```

I expect some seasoned perlers have many good reasons not to do this.

Answer (score 0):

yon can also try some stuff like this!!!

```
# I want to find file xyz.txt in $dir (say C:\sandbox)

    Findfile("xyz.txt", $dir);

    sub Findfile ()
    {
        my $file = shift;
        my $Searchdir = shift;

        my @content = <$Searchdir/*>; 

        foreach my $element (@content)
        {
             if($element =~ /.*$file$/)
             {
                print "found";
                last;
             }
             elsif (-d $element)
             {
                 Findfile($file, $element); #recursive search
             }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to _StackOverflow_, you might want to read [how to post an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before doing so. Give a bit of context explaining why you posted that code and what does it do. Also consider taking the time to format your answer to be easily understood by readers.

Answer (score -1):

[File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find::Rule) is "smoother".

```
use File::Find::Rule qw( );
say for File::Fine::Rule->in(".");
```