# Find command - How to cut short after finding first file

Tags: linux, find, abort

I am using the find command to check if a certain pattern of
file exists within a directory tree. (Note, anywhere down the tree)

Once the first file is found the checking can stop because the answer is "yes".
How can I stop "find" from continuing the unnecessary search for other files?

Limiting -maxdepth does not work for the obvious reason that I am checking
any where down the tree.

I tried -exec exit ; and -exec quit ;
Hoping there was a linux command to call via -exec that would stop processing.
Should I write a script (to call via -exec above) that kills the find process
but continues running my script?

Additional detail: I am calling find from a perl script.
I don't necessarily have to use 'find' if there are other tools.
I may have to resolve to walking the dir-path via a longer perl script that I can control
when to stop.

I also looked into -prune option but it seems to be valid only up front (globally)
and can't change it in the middle of processing.

This was one instance of my find command that worked and returned all occurrences of the file pattern.
find /media/pk/mm2020A1/00.staging /media/pk/mm2020A1/x.folders -name *hevc* -o -name '*HEVC*' -o -name '*265*'

Comment: This was one instance of the find command. But I am making it into a utility where both the directories and file-patterns are viariables.  find /media/pk/mm2020A1/00.staging /media/pk/mm2020A1/x.folders  -iname '*HEVC*' -o -name '*265*'

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something along the lines of

```
find . -name '*.csv' | wc -l
```

and then ask whether that is `-gt 0`,
with the detail that we'd like to exit
early if possible, to conserve compute resources.

Well, here's a start:

```
find . -name '*.csv' | head -1
```

It doesn't *exactly* bail after finding first match,
since there's a race condition,
but it keeps you from spending two minutes
recursing down a deep directory tree.

In particular, after receiving 1st result `head`
will `close()` stdin, so `find` won't be able
to write to stdout, and it soon will exit.

---

I don't know your business use case.
But you may find it convenient and performant
to record `find . -ls | sort  > files.txt`
every now and again,
and have your script consult *that* file.
It typically takes less time to access those stored results
than to re-run `find`, that is, to once again
recurse through the directory trees.

Why? It's a random I/O versus sequential access story.

---

You can exit earlier if you adopt
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5090067/8431111)
technique:

```perl
use Path::Class;

dir('.')->recurse( ...
```

Comment: J_H , impressive answer - 3 ways each addressing my very issue.  How do I rate your answer so you get more gold medals. @J_H